# Can only iterate over an array

Tags: java

```
enum Bags {
    SMALL(10832, 10000000), MEDIUM(10833, 100000000), HUGE(10834, 100000000), HEFTY(
            10835, 2147000000);

    public int id, mAmount;

    Bags(int id, int mAmount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mAmount = mAmount;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getMoneyAmount() {
        return mAmount;
    }

    public Bags getBagConfig(int index) {

        for (Bags bag : Bags.values()) {

            for (int bagId : bag.getId()) {

                if (bagId == index) {
                    return bag;
                }

            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static void init(final Client c, final int itemUsed,
        final int useWith) {
    if (itemUsed == 7 && useWith == 1) {
        c.getItems().deleteItem(7, 1);
    }
    c.eventContainer.addEvent(new CycleEvent(5) {

        public void execute() {
            c.getItems().addItem(1, 3);
        }
    });
}
```

It says: `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable`
Can someone please help me out with this?

I don't know how to fix this error, the error is on the for loop.

Comment: It's the 2nd for loop causing the problem. You're trying to iterate over bag.getId(), which is just a single int.

Comment: So, I should make the int a int[][]?

Comment: Repeating the problem in a huge chunk of text is really terrible.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Use an if statement instead of a for loop

Answer (score 4):

The error message is correct, this

```
for (Bags bag : Bags.values()) {
  for (int bagId : bag.getId()) { // <-- HERE!
    if (bagId == index) {
      return bag;
    }
  }
}
```

Is not legal. I think you wanted

```
for (Bags bag : Bags.values()) {
  if (bag.getId() == index) {
    return bag;
  }
}
```

Because `getId()` returns a single `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
for (int bagId : bag.getId()) {
    if (bagId == index) {
         return bag;
    }
}
```

with

```
if (bag.getId() == index) {
     return bag;
}
```